# SELECT QUERY WITH UPDATE QUERY,send email if a MYSQL field changes

Tags: php, mysql, select, cron, sql-update

I have a cron job setup to look every 24 hours for a change in value in subscription table like this, here if current date becomes more than end date of subscription, status field value becomes 'inactive'

```
$curdate=date('Y-m-d'); 

$sql=("UPDATE subscription SET status='inactive' WHERE (end_date < '$curdate')");
```

I would like to send an email to the user whose subscription has just expired using the above cron job, for which i needs to retrieve the user_id also stored in the same subscription table..

Is there a way i can run a SELECT QUERY along with the above UPDATE QUERY and retrieve the user_id of the user whose subscription has just expired?

Thanks,

Comment: Do a query for `SELECT userid FROM subscription WHERE status = 'inactive' AND end_date < '$curdate' LIMIT 0, 1000` before you update.

Comment: Jared, that wouldn't work as there will be numerous other entries in MYSQL where (end_date < '$curdate') for a lot of previous users whose subscription has previously expired. if i were to run a select where end_date<curdate AND status 'active' that wouldnt work either as cron makes them inactive everyday as well..

Comment: Oops, that should have been `status = 'active'`. Not sure what you mean by your second sentence.

Comment: Jared. this worked like a charm, i've adjusted Marc B. response below to show the same. thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two stages:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM subscriptions
WHERE status='active' AND (end_date < '$curdate')
```

to retrieve all the expiring ids. Take that list of ids and stuff it into your update query:

```
UPDATE subscriptions SET ... WHERE (user_id IN ($list_of_ids_from_before))
```

Then re-use the ID list to generate your emails.

Comment: You know, I'm wondering if a `status` field is even necessary given the logic for deactivating...

Comment: In the select query? Wouldn't want to re-spam users who were deactivated in previous runs and opted to NOT reactivate.

Comment: Or, another field for notified could be used. I'm just saying, in general it appears that the logic for what is "not active" is pretty clear (and not really a comment on your answer, just in general).

Comment: First step is select user_id where status is active and end_date < curdate then email all the users using a while loop based on the user_id we got above (innerjoin user_id with user email info table) third and final step would be to update the table and set status to 'inactive or expired' after end date is over

Answer (score 0):

You can

A. Run your select first and get the user_ids that are about to expire, then run the query to expire them. There is a risk that you may run your update twice if it fails the first time.

B. You can create a trigger on subscription to write a record into an expire notification queue or the like that your cron script can consume and generate emails

C. you can add an expired date to your subscription table and then query the table after the fact to find subscriptions that expired "today"

Answer (score 0):

Use a transaction and execute a SELECT statement with the same WHERE condition first.